# File field acting like it's required when it's not

Tags: ee2, control-panel, file-uploads

I've got a channel set up that includes a couple of file fields that allow editors to add images to entries. I have these fields set up to accept images only and as not required, but when I try to publish entries, I'm seeing error messages on those fields saying "You did not select a file to upload."

If I choose an image for both fields, I'm able to Submit the entry form and save the entry.

Also, once the entry is saved, If I edit it, I'm able to remove the images from the fields and re-submit and the entry will save.

But if I edit the entry again and try to submit it without re-adding the images, I'm unable to save.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any ideas?

This site is running EE 2.7.1 and I'm seeing this issue on both production and local environments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19732

I ended up setting the allowed upload directories to "all" per the recommended workaround.